# Script doesn't work correct

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use this script to show buttons on my page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function buttonize(cellvalue, options, rowobject) {
        var buttons;

        if (rowobject[5] == "False") {
            buttons += '<input type="button" value="Edit" onclick="editQuestionnaire(' + options.rowId + ')">';
        }

        buttons += '<input type="button" value="Delete" onclick="deleteQuestionnaire(' + options.rowId + ')">';

        return buttons;
    }
</script>
```

I get buttons that I need, but also I get `undefined` before buttons.
How to make it does not appear?

Comment: On which line are you getting `undefined`?

Comment: Your input is not closed (no `</input>` or simple `/>` at the end of the input), that may cause you some problems

Comment: Please post a link to a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) so we can see the behaviour.

Comment: Thanks all of you, but I got answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare `buttons` with empty string:

```
var buttons = '';
```

Answer (score 4):

You have not initialized your variable with any value here:

```
var buttons;
```

so its value is undefined.

Then you are appending string data to it

```
buttons += '<input type="...
```

so its current value has to be converted to a string before - and that gets you "undefined".

So just initialize your variable with an empty string at the beginning:

```
var buttons = "";
```

Answer (score 1):

try to initialize the variable buttons.

```
var buttons = ''; // since it will contain string..use ''
```